# jQuery Initiating the function from a select element

Tags: jquery, forms, image, gallery

OK, I have been working on the next problem for a few hours now, to no avail. I am learning - so that's good!

Here is my issue. I am using a Image Zoom + Thumbnails plugin for jQuery.
There is a main image identified as img#zoom-primary and below this there are thumbnails (clicking on them changes the main image) these can be identified by the class .imageToSwap

I have a dropdown list of options (in a form) for a particular product and want to change the main image and the corresponding thumbnails depending in the option chosen (eg colour). That way the product images change with the colour option.

There are 8 images associated with each option. Thus, I want to change the image src and href increasing the image number by 1 each time. EG image-1.png, image-2.png etc.

This is the function that I have come up with - with some help (thank you)!

```
var currentImageTS = 1;
function updateImageTS() {

$('img#zoom-primary').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + "0.png");


$(".imageToSwap").each (function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + currentImageTS + ".png")
    .attr('http', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + currentImageTS + ".png");

    currentImageTS++;
    if (currentImageTS > 8) currentImageTS = 1;



})

}
```

Essentially, when a user selects something from the dropdown menu, the main image needs to change, so too all the thumbnails. The main image only has a img src, whereas the thumbnails have an img src and a a href

The above code has been included in an external javascript file - which is running all sorts of other javascript so it is included and working.

In my form i have the following code to call the function:

```
<select onchange="$(updateImageTS())" />
```

But it does not seem to be working! I'm guessing this is where the problem is.

Any help as to where I am going wrong and what I should try would be gratefully received.

My background is php so learning jQuery is a challenge (i have very little experience of javascript)!

Thank you

---

Thank you Jeto,
I have read that document over and over! 
This is what I have come up with (but still failing to work) - i put this within the page itself, at the bottom, rather than inserting it into the external js file - :

```
<script>
$( ".imageOptions" )
  .change(function () {
var currentImageTS = 1;
$('img#zoom-primary').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + "0.png");


$(".imageToSwap").each (function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + currentImageTS + ".png")
    .attr('http', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + currentImageTS + ".png");

    currentImageTS++;
    if (currentImageTS > 8) currentImageTS = 1;

})
})
  .change();
</script>
```

And i have made the select :

```
<select class="imageOptions" />
```

I just cannot see how the functions work! I think my knowledge of php is confusing me!

Comment: Take a look at [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/). This is how you listen for change events on your select dropdowns using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried many different approaches to no avail. I have updated the original post. Any assistance would be grateful.